# converting char* to string* in C++

Tags: c++, string, pointers, stdvector, c-strings

I have the following structure:

```
struct SimpleCommand {

  // Simple command is simply a vector of strings
  std::vector<std::string *> _arguments;

  SimpleCommand();
  ~SimpleCommand();
  void insertArgument( std::string * argument );
  void print();
};
```

I want to call the `insertArgument` function with an arguments of type `char*` that are given to me in an array, in a loop. If I call it with the following code:

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
   insertArgument(array[i]);
}
```

it won't compile and gives me an

```
cannot convert ‘char*’ to ‘std::string*’
```

error. If I use the following code as suggested:

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
   std:string s(array[i]);
   insertArgument(&s);
}
```

all the values in the vector point to the same string. How do I resolve this issue.

Comment: I wonder why a `std::string*` for a method called `insertArgument`, looks like `const std::string&` would have been more appropriate

Comment: why pointer to std::string, an unusual thing to do

Comment: Why do you have a `std::vector` of `std::string*` and not just a `std::vector` of `std::string`? You almost never need a pointer to a `std::string`.

Comment: Maybe it's a polymorphic `std::string`.

Answer (score 2):

For starters it is unclear why the function is declared like

```
void insertArgument( std::string * argument );
```

instead of

```
void insertArgument( const std::string &argument );
```

and correspondingly the vector should be declared like

```
std::vector<std::string> _arguments;
```

As for your question then instead of this for loop

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
   std:string s(array[i]);
   insertArgument(&s);
}
```

you need to write

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
   std:string *s = new std::string{ array[i] };
   insertArgument( s );
}
```

In this case the class is responsible to delete the memory allocated for strings when they will not be needed any more.

Answer (score 0):

You might store the string in a local variable:

```
char* cs;
std::string s(cs);
insertArgument(&s);
```

---

However, if you'd like to keep the strings, it's best if you store it in a `std::vector<std::string>` and take a `std::string` in `insertArgument()` (vs. `std::string*`).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This resolves the compilation error but introduces a new one. The code does not seem to work in a loop.  Please see my edited question. Thanks.

Comment: I suspect insertArgument()

just store the pointer to 

std::vector<std::string *> _arguments;

this cannot work, change :

std::vector<std::string> _arguments;

Comment: Original post didn't contain the new information that you store it in a vector. Changing answer accordingly.